# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python

В Парсере валют почему-то выдаёт такую ошибку TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'NoneType' , уже пол дня морочусь как бы её исправить, не могу найти ответ, прошу помощи, спасибо.

P.S l Ошибка выдаётся из-за предпоследней строки  result = number / dollar_uah()

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

DOLLAR_UAH = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80+%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0&oq=%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80+%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0i20i263i512j0i512l8.2878j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.75 Safari/537.36'}

def dollar_uah():
    full_page = requests.get (DOLLAR_UAH, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(full_page.content, 'html.parser')

    convert = soup.findAll("span", {"class" : "DFlfde", "class" : "SwHCTb", "data-precision": 2})

    convert[0].text.replace(",", ".") 

what_value = {
    "1",
    "2",
    "3"
}




while True:
    what = input("\nВыберите, что вы отдаете: \n 1 - Доллар , 2 - Гривна: ")
    if what not in what_value:
        print("Ошибка")
        exit()

    what2 = input("Выберите, что вы получаете: \n 1 - Доллар , 2 - Гривна: ")
    
    if what2 not in what_value:
        print("Ошибка")
        exit()


    while True:
        try:
            number = float( input("Введите сколько вы хотите посчитать: "))
        except ValueError:
            print('Введите число')
        else:
            break

    #Доллары в гривны
    if what == "1" and what2 == "2":
        result = number / dollar_uah()
        print ("Результат: " + str(result))
```

Comment: Что вот это result = number / dollar_uah() ?

Comment: dollar_uah() это функция которая парсит с гугла курс валют доллар-гривна. Результат = Число которое человек ввёл поделить на курс доллара, примерно 30, то есть 100 долларов 3000 гривен

Comment: вы бы строку указывали, на которую ошибка выдана. Правда, уже указал @СергейШашко :-)

Comment: функция dollar_uah() возвращает не число, а None, о чём и сообщается.

Comment: кто то забыл написать return полученного значения...

Comment: Так и шо мне получается делать?

Comment: А что хотелось бы получить? Делить number на None - есть ли смысл? Может закончить функцию return, как водится в лучших домах?

Comment: 1) Попросить автора кода дописать return в функцию. 2) Посмотреть в учебнике, как это делается:-) 
На всякий случай: не во всех функциях return нужен, но этой - нужен

Comment: return float(convert[0].text.replace(",", ".") )  - не?

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно в конце функции написать:
return float(convert[0].text.replace(",", ".") )

Comment: восстановите, пожалуйста свой удаленный [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1553031/28748) Если вам не нужен ответ, то кому-нибудь точно пригодится в аналогичной ситуации

Answer (score 0):

Ваша функция ничего не возвращает, а None — это и есть ничего. Нужно в конце функции заменить последнюю строку на: `return float(convert[0].text.replace(",", "."))`.

P.S. Программа говорила Вам, что нельзя делить число с плавающей точкой на `None`